# Access data injected into grandchild component

Tags: reactjs, graphql, containers

The grandchild component is wrapped in a container which receives data via a graphql query.
I need to access that data from the Grandparent component in order to check the values in the data set to perform some functionality .
How can I read what data the grandchild has received?

Comment: This sounds like the data should be fetched higher up, within that grandparent component.

Comment: Use [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Answer (score 1):

Pass a function from grand parent to the grand child component (you may have to pass it two levels deep, e.g. via `Child`), then
the **grand child will invoke that function** (because it received it from props) and pass the data it wants as parameter - hence grand parent will have chance to respond.

Rough sketch:

```
class GrandParent{


// This function will get called when grand child receives data
dataReceivedInGrandChild(data){

  //Do whatever you want with data

}


render(){

   ....
   <Child dataReceivedInGrandChild={this.dataReceivedInGrandChild}/>
   ....

}



}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can make a function within the grandchild to return the desired data, then add refs to the parent and to the grandchild and in the grandparent you have to refer to these refs e.g.:

grandP.parent.grandC.getData

or you can fetch the data within the grandparent and path it via props to child and to grandchild